# Get just inserted id

Tags: zend-framework

I have here many-to-many table, i need to get just inserted id - BlogId. lastInsertId() is NULL result. Any ideas?

```
 $table = new Blog_Model_Blog_Table();
    $relTable = new Blog_Model_Relation_Table();
        $Object = $table->createRow();
        $form = new Blog_Form_Blog_Add($Object);
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() and $form->isValid($_POST)) {
            Blog_Model_Blog_Manager::add($Object);
            $blogId = $table->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
            foreach ($_POST['category_id'] as $value) {
                $relTable->insert(array('id' => $blogId, 'category_id' => $value));
            }
```

Blog_Model_Blog_Manager:

```
 class Blog_Model_Blog_Manager
{
    static function add(Blog_Model_Blog_Item &$Object)
    {
        $data = array(
            'time_add'              =>  time(),
            'time_edit'             =>  time(),
            'url_keyword'           =>  Ap_Filter_Translit::asURLSegment($Object->name)
        );
        $Object->setFromArray($data)
               ->save();
    }
```

Comment: if `Blog_Model_Blog_Manager::add($Object);` has any effect on $table make sure you return all the data you'll need later. `$blogId = $table->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();` may or may not return a value, depending on which database you're using and also depending on the context of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it with mySql function LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
$blogId = $table->fetchRow($table->select()->from($table)->columns('LAST_INSERT_ID() as idi'));
```